# How to generate one-time-address using python?

Tags: stealth-address, eddsa

I want to calculate monero one-time-address step by step using python. But I don't know how.
Some steps confused me in this formula `k = Hn(k_B^v*R)*G + K_B^s`. `Hn` means keccak-256, `k_B^v` means Bob's secret view key, `R` means transaction public key, `G` means ed25519 base point, and finalLy `K_B^s` means Bob's public spend key.

(1)Can I directly use hex format to calculate rather point format?

(2)In multiple output transaction, how can I append output index `t` to `k_B^v*R`. Should I conduct keccak-256 twice?

Thanks so much for your help.